# " Did you were at home ? " or "Were you at home ?"

Tags: past-tense, simple-past

I don't know when I should use "*Did you were...*" and when I should use "*Were you...*".
For example, Why do we say:

> "*Were you at home last night?*"

but not

> "*Did you were at home last night?*"

Comment: A more challenging question—because it doesn't involve running afoul of grammatical rules governing how to indicate that something happened in the past without over-identifying it as past—might be "Why isn't 'Did you be at home?' a standard alternative way of inquiring about whether someone was at home at a particular time in the past?"

Answer (score 2):

You would never use **"Did you were"** in proper English, because "did" is the past tense of "do," a verb. Example: **"I did my homework last night."** Also, you could correctly ask, **"Did you stay home last night?"** instead of **"Were you home last night?"** Both are acceptable usage.

Comment: I agree with Mark. I've never heard "Did you were" used in informal/idiomatic English, either. I would call that a grammatical error.